# Can i connect to 2 database in pro c code on Linux

Tags: c, linux

I wanted to connect to 2 database at the same time in pro c code on Linux, and run SQL queries simultaneously on both the databases in single running application.  Is this possible. Please suggest.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from executing your SQL queries as usual, only twice for each?

Comment: I am able to connect to 2 DB now simultaneously. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can use below syntax for this

EXEC SQL CONNECT :uName1 IDENTIFIED BY :passwd1 AT :DB_NAME1 USING :dbString1

EXEC SQL CONNECT :uName2 IDENTIFIED BY :passwd2 AT :DB_NAME2 USING :dbString2

EXEC SQL at :DB_NAME1 SELECT .....

EXEC SQL at :DB_NAME2 SELECT .....